# How to link EmailAuthProvider with FacebookAuthProvider in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I try to merge email/password account with Facebook account. The scenario is like:

- user created an account in my app (email/password provider)
- one week later, he can't remember that he created his account with Google or Facebook or Email/Password, so he clicks to sign in with Facebook.
- an error message appears auth/account-exists-with-different-credential - that's ok, understand that.
- fetchSignInMethodsForEmail sends me 'password' provider with flag isOAuthProvider: false which means I can't directly sign in with FB.

What should I do next to log in with Fb and then link that account with existed email/password account of that user?

Should I redirect the user to email/password form and tell him (toast) why should he try to log in this way, or there is a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the steps you've described, I see two logical options:

1. Indeed let the user complete the sign-in with Facebook, and sign-in with their email/password, and then link those accounts.
2. Tell them that they signed in with email/password before, and redirect them to that.

Linking the accounts is typically a nicer flow for the user, but it is more work to get working.

Comment: Is it possible to finish sign-in with Facebook in this scenario if I disallow multiple accounts with the same email address?

Comment: As long as you follow the flow described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking. Key is that you can't call one of the `FirebaseAuth.signInWith...` methods yet. Instead of that you use `linkWithCredential`.

Comment: Thx Frank, I will try!